# Is it possible to include OpenOffice Writer or MS Word data in a ReportLab generated PDF?

Tags: python, ms-word, reportlab, openoffice-writer

The desire is to have the user provide information in an OpenOffice Writer or MS Word file that is inserted into part of a ReportLab generated PDF. I am comfortable with ReportLab; but, I don't have any experience with using Writer or Word data in this way. How would you automate the process of pulling in the Writer/Word data? Is it possible to retain tables and graphs?

Answer (score 0):

You can not embed such objects as is within a PDF, adobe specification does not support that. However you could always parse the data from the Office document and reproduce it as a table/graph/etc using reportlab in the output PDF. If you don't care about the data being an actual text you could always save it in the PDF as an image.